# On Rust Setters

Tags: rust, set, setter

I have looked on Stack Overflow for ways to set values within a declared mutable struct. The answers did not look straightforward, and for me, strayed too far away from simplicity that I enjoy. I eventually found out from tinkering around that this code works as desired:

```
struct FooStruct {
    bar: i32,
}

impl FooStruct {

    fn set(&mut self, val: i32){
        //*self.first_name_mut() = val;
        *(&mut self.bar) = val;
    }

}

fn main() {
    let mut k = 45;
    let mut my_person = FooStruct { bar: 2};

    println!("Fn: {}", my_person.bar);
    my_person.set(k);
    println!("Fn: {}", my_person.bar); //value is printed as 45
    k = 33; // set k-value
    println!("Fn: {}", my_person.bar); //the value in the struct remains as 45, unchanged
}
```

Notice how simple it is to implement a setter:

```
*(&mut self.bar) = val;
```

My question is: is there a catch to this simplicity of setting a value? People have went as far as creating macros for getting/setting, so I'm wondering why this method isn't used. I'm coming from Java-land, where setting is a mindless deal (this.value = input); upon arrival where rustaceans live, I expected OOP-like features to be a nuisance to implement.

While I hope this post helps people implement a setter, I also want an experienced user to explain what the line of code above is doing as well as any pitfalls that I have not (possibly yet) seen.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but `self.bar = val;` would have worked fine.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I am curious though, because I thought that "bar" is immutable?

Comment: bar's mutability is inherited from the object which it is a member of, in this case, `*self`.

Comment: Does a struct's mutability inherent to all its members? This experiment seems to imply so.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you

Comment: With that said, is there ever a reason to declare a struct's inner-member as mutable if all you have to do is declare an initiated struct as mutable?

Comment: There is no concept of a mutable member. All members inherit the mutability of the object of which they are a part.

Comment: There is *kind of* a concept of a mutable member: `UnsafeCell`. You can use `UnsafeCell` (or something based on it, like `Cell`, `RefCell`, atomics, or `Mutex`) to have a member of a struct that is mutable even with only a shared reference to the struct. But that route *does* make mutating the member more syntactically complicated.

Comment: While the answer is fine, I don't think this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow, which favors questions with clear-cut answers and not so much open-ended discussions. A discussion forum like users.rust-lang.org is where I would usually suggest posting something like this. If you can rewrite your question to *be* more of a question -- like "how do I set a member of a struct?" -- then SO would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Mutability is inherited from the parent object, in this case "my_person", because it was declared as "mut". As such, as Benjamin Lindley pointed, all you have to do is replace:

```
*(&mut self.bar) = val;
```

with:

```
self.bar = val;
```

Lesson: mutability propagates from the parent object downwards into the structure if the object is declared mutable